# Adding minutes to time in format h:i A in php giving unexpected results

Tags: php, strtotime

I have time in my DB in format 12:30 PM 07:30 AM etc. I need it in format **['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], 
['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']...**
The time is in UTC format. I have a function to convert it into local time based on user time zone.

```
function convertTimeToUSERzone($str, $userTimezone, $format = 'h:i A'){
if(empty($str)){
return '';
}
$new_str = new DateTime($str, new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
$new_str->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone( $userTimezone ));
return $new_str->format( $format);
}
```

15 minutes need to be added to time from DB, example 12:15 PM to 12:30 PM. I have done the following and it gives unexpected results.

```
while($r = $stmt3->fetch())
{
$consult_time_UTC[] = $r['consult_time_utc'];
}
$consult_time_UTC = implode(',',$consult_time_UTC); 
$date = new DateTime($consult_time_UTC);
$date->add(new DateInterval("PT{15}M"));
$to = $date->format('h:i A'); //require format as ['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']
//.....
}
```

I was trying to add 15 minutes to existing time. How to add 15 minutes to time in h:i A format  to each array element and obtain in format `['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']` ? Confused Newbie.

Comment: `DateInterval("PT15M"))`

Comment: @splash58 Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (12:30 PM,07:30 AM) at position 6 (P): The timezone could not be found in the database

Comment: why do you set DateTime with two time values?

Comment: https://eval.in/892965

Comment: @splash58 My time picker is set as increments of 15 minutes and it needs to be in format  ['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM'] for detecting already selected date.

Comment: So, $consult_time_UTC is array of 2 items or string?

Comment: @@splash58 I could understand add(new DateInterval for single dates. But i am running explode on array to make it csv. and after that i need it in format  ['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM'] ?? It could be multiple values too depending on time already selected. I need to disable the selected values in timepicker. This is an ajax request for the selected values based on date selected.

Comment: Do add TimeInterval for each  item of $consult_time_UTC and then implode

Comment: @splash58 I tried the following without success. Internal server error:
while($r = $stmt3->fetch())
{
$consult_time_UTC = new DateTime($r['consult_time_utc']);
$consult_time_UTC->add(new DateInterval("PT15M"));
$consult_time_UTC1 = $consult_time_UTC->format('h:i A');
$consult_time_UTC[] = ('['.$consult_time_UTC,$consult_time_UTC1.']');
}
$consult_time_UTC = implode(',',$consult_time_UTC); 
echo $consult_time_UTC;
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but in any case you should to add time interval to each array item. Something like this

```
while($r = $stmt3->fetch())
{
   $r['consult_time_utc'];
   $date = new DateTime($consult_time_UTC);
   $date->add(new DateInterval("PT15M"));
   $consult_time_UTC[] = $date->format('h:i A');
}
$consult_time_UTC = implode(',',$consult_time_UTC);
```